# Option clash for package hyperref when using APA format templates

Tags: hyperref

When I build my LaTeX Project with an APA template, I intend to cancel the red-square shown around the hyperlink in contents. Following with the guide I tried the commend
`\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}`, but when building the project it shows the error

> option clash for package hyperref

**Here is my code at the beginning**

```
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{\textit{\Large Bob Dylan and Richard Brautigan}:\\ Ballads and poems embodying the zeitgeist of U.S. society in Counterculture Movement in the 1960s}
\shorttitle{}%Zeitgeist of U.S. Society
\author{3984 Words}
\affiliation{}
\leftheader{\quad}
%\abstract{\lipsum[1]}

\keywords{Bob Dylan, Richard Brautigan, Counterculture Movement}


\begin{document}
\vspace*{50mm}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Large Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

Please guide me what I should do. Thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please do not post pictures of code but the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

apa7 already loads hyperref but with a different set of options. You can override this in two ways. One thing that always work is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black}{hyperref}
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

another one is to use `\hypersetup`. This is specific to hyperref and doesn't work with all options. I removed the setting for anchorcolor as this color is normally not used anywhere.

```
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black}
\begin{document}
blub 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does work!!! I choose to use `\PassOptionsToPackage` and it ultimately provides the solution. Thank you very much!